# Would one-click installation delete previous website?

Tags: wordpress

I am helping a friend build a simple Wordpress website, their current website is with a hosting and domain service called https://www.icuk.net/.

The website is very poorly built on this platform. I told them I'd make a website for free on WordPress as I have some experience with drag and drop WordPress website builders.

My question is, if I use the platform's one-click WordPress installation, does it automatically delete the website that was previously using the domain and hosting? If so, could anyone explain in layman's terms how I would go about backing it up, as it's always better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: That's a question for their support, surely? We can't tell you what their functionality is.

Answer (score -1):

I would be hesitant to do this, personally. I believe you can use the one click service to uninstall, at which point you can install WP again. A better option, however, if WP is already installed, would be to just change the theme, deactivate and delete any unwanted plugins, and then delete (or change to draft if you may want any of the content for your new development) any unwanted posts or pages. A current version of WP is a current version of WP, thus there is no reason to reinstall. Once you change the theme, remove the posts and pages, and remove the plugins, you are essentially back to a new install. Maybe do that instead?